# Mysql error: 1292 Incorrect datetime value showing a date that doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-error-1292

I'm getting an error with this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `populateTimeTable`(IN table_name VARCHAR(45), IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE)
BEGIN

DECLARE full_date DATE;

SET @query_create = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' ,table_name, '(
    idDate INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    year SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    quarter TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    month tinyint(2) unsigned not null,
    month_name ENUM(''January'',''February'',''March'',''April'',''May'',''June'',''July'',''August'',''September'',''October'',''November'',''December'') NOT NULL,
    month_name_spanish ENUM(''Enero'',''Febrero'',''Marzo'',''Abril'',''Mayo'',''Junio'',''Julio'',''Agosto'',''Septiembre'',''Octubre'',''Noviembre'',''Diciembre'') NOT NULL,
    week TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    day TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    weekday TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    weekday_name ENUM(''Monday'',''Tuesday'',''Wednesday'',''Thursday'',''Friday'',''Saturday'',''Sunday'') NOT NULL,
    weekday_name_spanish ENUM(''Lunes'',''Martes'',''Miércoles'',''Jueves'',''Viernes'',''Sábado'',''Domingo'') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idDate)
)');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query_create;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SET @query_delete = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ' ,table_name);
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @query_delete;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

SET full_date = start_date;

WHILE full_date <= end_date
DO
    SET @query_insert = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ' ,table_name, '(
        idDate,
        date,
        year,
        quarter,
        month,
        month_name,
        month_name_spanish,
        week,
        day,
        weekday,
        weekday_name,
        weekday_name_spanish
    ) VALUES ( 
        DATE_FORMAT(' ,full_date, ', "%Y%m%d"),'
        ,full_date, ',
        YEAR(' ,full_date, '),
        QUARTER(' ,full_date, '),
        MONTH(' ,full_date, '),
        MONTHNAME(' ,full_date, '),
        (SELECT CASE MONTH(' ,full_date, ')
            WHEN 1 THEN ''Enero''
            WHEN 2 THEN ''Febrero''
            WHEN 3 THEN ''Marzo''
            WHEN 4 THEN ''Abril''
            WHEN 5 THEN ''Mayo''
            WHEN 6 THEN ''Junio''
            WHEN 7 THEN ''Julio''
            WHEN 8 THEN ''Agosto''
            WHEN 9 THEN ''Septiembre''
            WHEN 10 THEN ''Octubre''
            WHEN 11 THEN ''Noviembre''
            WHEN 12 THEN ''Diciembre''
        END),
        WEEK(' ,full_date, ', 5),
        DAY(' ,full_date, '),
        WEEKDAY(' ,full_date, ') + 1,
        DAYNAME(' ,full_date, '),
        (SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(' ,full_date, ')
            WHEN 1 THEN ''Domingo''
            WHEN 2 THEN ''Lunes''
            WHEN 3 THEN ''Martes''
            WHEN 4 THEN ''Miércoles''
            WHEN 5 THEN ''Jueves''
            WHEN 6 THEN ''Viernes''
            WHEN 7 THEN ''Sábado''
        END)
    )');
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @query_insert;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

    SET full_date = DATE_ADD(full_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;
END
```

IF I execute:

```
CALL populateTimeTable('dim_time','1900-04-01','1901-01-01')
```

I get:

```
Error Code: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1895'
```

Removing all the prepared statements and using a fixed table name, it works, so the problem is with the prepared statement stmt3.

If I change the start date, I get the same error but with different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have quotes around `full_date` in the query string you are creating.  So, you are getting something like:

```
VALUES ( 
        DATE_FORMAT( 1900-04-01, "%Y%m%d"),'
        1900-04-01,
        . . .
```

This is different from:

```
VALUES ( 
        DATE_FORMAT('1900-04-01', "%Y%m%d"),'
        1900-04-01,
        . . .
```

Your version does an arithmetic calculation (1900 - 04 - 01 = 1895), so it turns into:

```
VALUES ( 
        DATE_FORMAT( 1895, "%Y%m%d"),'
        1895,
        . . .
```

By the way, I'm guessing that this would have been quite obvious if you had looked at the string after variable substitution.  Whenever you use dynamic SQL, you should *always* be looking at the query strings being produced.

You can fix this by putting single quote delimited throughout your statement.  Or, better yet, parameterize the statement and use `EXECUTE . . . USING` (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)).

EDIT:

You can write the query in the form:

```
insert into table_name(. . . )
    select DATE_FORMAT(full_date, '%Y%m%d), 
           full_date,
           YEAR(full_date),
           . . .
    from (select ? as full_date, . . .) t;
```

Each parameters goes in the subquery.  The values can then be used in the outer query.

Comment: I think I should prepare the statement before the loop and execute it in it, so parameterize the statement would be the way. Do you know if it's possible to use the same parameter in different places of the query without passing it for every parameter marker. (I would have to pass full_date 12 times).

Comment: @vjsp90 . . . If you change the `insert . . . values` to an `insert . . . select`, you can put the parameters in a subquery and give them name

Comment: I think I don't understand you. What I say is something like: SET @ query =... ?1, year(?1), month(?1).... and into the loop execute  @ query using @ full_date for ?1. Do you say something like SELECT ? as my_date and then use my_date as parameter?